# Synchronize request to database in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, redis

I have a postgres table TABLE_A that looks like this:

```
TABLE_A:
id
name
```

I populate the table like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES(1, 'one')
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES(2, 'two')
INSERT INTO TABLE_A VALUES(3, 'three')
```

Then I have a redis DB where a row has the following content:

```
{
"idsAndRoles":
    [
        {"id":1,"roles":["A","B"]}
        ,{"id":2,"roles":["A"]}
    ]
}
```

Now, the entry in redis above has to be "merged" with content from postgres. And Im using node to do this.

So the first thing I do is to return a new Promise like this:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    redis.hget("myredisdb", "mykey", function(err, res){
        //Here i get from redis the row I described above
    });
}
```

Where you see the comment, I do an iteration to fetch all the ids and for each id I also can come over the array with roles.
However, I still need to "merge" the postgres table TABLE_A.
Basically, at the end of the operation I need a structure that with the data above would return:

```
{
"idsAndRoles":
    [
        {"id":1, "name": "one", "roles":["A","B"]}
        ,{"id":2,"name": "two", "roles":["A"]}
    ]
}
```

So more or less, either merge data from redis to postgres or viceversa.

The problem is that I cannot make a loop and for each element query postgres, beacuse Im using node with asynch operations.
What is the way to solve this situations? Im sure there must have been a lot of people having the same issue.

Comment: why async blocks merging?.. show the js code where you forEach or how every you want to do it

Comment: So it boils down to - `you cannot get an async loop to work`. That's trivial when using promises, and there's ton of posts here about it, if you search. Specifically for Node + PostgreSQL there is [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) which makes looping through data a breeze.